# Can you change the text content of a JSP file by code (on the fly)

Tags: java, spring, jsp

Lets say I have a jsp page in my webapp. The code inside it displays some info.

Can I change the code (text) inside this jsp using a Rest Controller. I want to dynamically replace its code by opening the file and changing its content.

I want to change file content via http request:

"/api/change-jsp?newcontent=sometext&file=example.jsp"

--> The corresponding rest controller now does his job.

Will that work or not ?

Ps: 'newcontent=sometext' contains jsp code (EL)

Comment: Thymeleaf with fragments and includes might be a good solution to what you're wanting to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't work — `jsp`s are compiled at runtime by the servlet container when the app starts. The JSP compiler will not expect the `jsp` to change.

But why change it in the first place? Just make the jsp ask for the information it needs.

Comment: Yes making the jsp ask for information works, but the information is just data. I wanted to inject new instructions into the jsp and replace the old ones. But I guess this doesnt work

Comment: Changing the jsp specific code after the app was deployed, without taking the app down

Comment: Are you talking about injecting java code from a request at runtime? That certainly won't work (it's a really bad idea, too). EL statements are data, though, and could easily be fetched from a dynamic source as strings without re-compiling the jsp

Comment: Yes inject java code at runtime. But as you said it wont work,  so thanks for clarification